# How to compute the divergence of a four-vector?

Tags: tensors, vector-calculus, differential-geometry

I have a quadri-vector which is given by

```
u = {(E^(-φ0[r]))*(1 - ε δφ[t, 
       r]), (E^(-φ0[r])) D[ε ξ[t, r], t], 0, 
  0}
```

and a quantity n which is given by

```
n = (n0[r] + εδn[t, r])
```

I want to calculate the divergence of `nu`, i.e. **∇**•(n**u**) send to `{t, r, θ, φ}` as coordinates.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is `n` or `nu`?  normal vector?

Comment: u is my four-vector and n is just a parameter that gives the number of particles in a star.

Comment: @IsabellaNunes since it's just a scalar multiplication, what's the issue with the simple `FullSimplify@Div[n*u, {t, r, θ, φ}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a general relativity 4-vector, it depends on the metric you use.  If for example we assume flat space with the convention that the time component is negative and the spacial components are positive, in this case the divergence can be computed this way:

```
u = {(E^(-φ0[r]))*(1 - ε δφ[t, r]), (E^(-φ0[r])) D[ε ξ[t, r], t], 0, 0}

n = (n0[r] + εδn[t, r])
```

Compute the n u 4-vector.

```
nu = n u
```

Take the regular positive divergence of the spacial 3 vector of the above in spherical coordinates and add the negative time contribution which is

-$\frac{1}{{c}}\frac{d}{{dt}}(n u[[1]])$

And we get

```
divnu = -(D[nu[[1]], t]/c) + Div[{nu[[2]], nu[[3]], nu[[4]]}, {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]}, 
 "Spherical"]//FullSimplify
```

If your problem has nothing to do with GR or a metric, you can skip multiplying the time portion by `-1/c`.

In my version v12.0, Mathematica will compute the divergence of a 4-vector directly if it is in Cartesian coordinates, but not Spherical coordinates.  The time portion must be added manually.